# Python Transform Key Value into new form

Tags: python

I have:

```
['key',{'key1':val1, 'key2':val2, 'key3':val3}]
```

how to arrive at:

```
[('key1','key'), ('key2','key'), ('key3','key')]
```

I would use list comprehension but I am ook here.

This is what I have so far:

```
[(k,j) for (k,v) in (j,(k,v))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = ['key',{'key1':val1, 'key2':val2, 'key3':val3}]
[(other_key, lst[0]) for other_key in lst[1]]
```

Not that order is not promised as `dict` is not ordered, so consider using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

Answer (score 0):

Using zip and itertools:

```
l = ['key',{'key1':"val1", 'key2':"val2", 'key3':"val3"}]

from itertools import repeat

print(list(zip(l[1],repeat(l[0]))))
[('key3', 'key'), ('key2', 'key'), ('key1', 'key')]
```